# Mariadb SQL syntax error while creating table

Tags: sql, mariadb

Manually creating a table while in mariadb console;
got the following error:

```
MariaDB [mysql]> CREATE TABLE learningdb(command varchar(255) text2disp varchar(255));
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'varchar(255))' at line 1

```
MariaDB [mysql]> CREATE TABLE learningdb(command varchar(2048) text2disp varchar(2048));
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'varchar(2048))' at line 1

Cannot find out the correct syntax.

Comment: Have you tried separating each field declaration by a comma? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mariadb/mariadb_create_tables.htm I'm no MariaDB expert but I guess that you need a primary key too.

Comment: Isn't this pretty much the definition of a typographical error?

Answer (score 2):

Dont you think a `comma separator` is required between each of type definition!?

**Example**:

```
CREATE TABLE learningdb(command varchar(255),  -- <--- this comma was missing
                        text2disp varchar(255));
```

**Refer to Documentation**:

- [***Create Table - Syntax***](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-table/)

  > ```
  > CREATE [OR REPLACE] [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
  >  (create_definition,...) ...
  > ```
- [***Tutorial Point: MariaDB - Create Tables***](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mariadb/mariadb_create_tables.htm)

  - ... Multiple columns separated by commas ...